# Encapsulating Entity Framework Migrations in a Nuget Package

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, nuget

I am creating a command line tool that will update the database using EF Migrations.

I want to encapsulate the EF Migrations business logic inside of a class library that is shared to the other teams with NuGet.

When the EF Migrations project as a *DLL* to the command line project all is good. When the EF Migrations *Nuget* package is added to the command line Project, the following error is returned from migrate.exe (EF Migrations executable).

> ERROR: Could not load assembly 'ProjectName'. (If you are
>   using Code First Migrations inside Visual Studio this can happen if
>   the startUp project for your solution does not reference the project
>   that contains your migrations. You can either change the startUp
>   project for your solution or use the -StartUpProjectName parameter.)

How can I get around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Any one run into this issue before?